# phpmyadmin is not using auth_type in config.inc.php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to show the html login form when logging in to phpmyadmin, however it continues to show the login popup, even though I have made the necessary changes in my config file. My config.inc.php file is located in the phpmyadmin directory as follows:

```
<?php
 $cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'secret';
 $i = 0;
 $i++;
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
 $cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
 $cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
?>
```

The install for phpmyadmin is located in /usr/share/phpmyadmin and I have created a symlink with a different name to this directory from /var/www. Does the symlink perhaps cause issues with the config file being loaded? Any other reason the auth_type = cookie is not actually working?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like the problem was that the config.inc.php in the root phpmyadmin was not the file that it was looking for. I needed to edit /etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php

Comment: Most distributions put their configuration files in /etc to adhere to their policy on configuration -- it looks like you're using the packaged version (which, incidentally, should not require you to symlink it to /var/www). They'll typically modify the phpMyAdmin program so that it looks in the appropriate folder (/etc/phpmyadmin). So yes, the correct place to put it would be in /etc/phpmyadmin/ as you've discovered.

Comment: View your config file path in `/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/vendor_config.php`.

Comment: Oh, and give read permission to your web server:  `/etc/phpMyAdmin/` and `/etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php`